# Llenar una matriz de 5 x 5 utilizando solamente un for en C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

Alguien sabe como llenar una matriz de 5 x 5 solamente utilizando un for?

Comment: Alberto. Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te pido que por favor leas la [guía sobre como realizar preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). La comunidad de StackOverflow estaremos contentos de apoyarte, siempre y cuando nos des más información sobre tu problema. Te comento que la comunidad no resuelve tareas escolares, pero si es capaz de ayudarte con errores en tu código.

Comment: Se me ocurre que cada 5 ciclos se compare su modulo algo como if(ciclo%5==0 && ciclo>0) y el contador del for este de 1 hasta 25

Answer (score 4):

Entiendo que la matriz es de tamaño fijo:

```
int matriz[5][5];
```

En este caso hay buenas noticias para ti, el compilador prepara esta matriz para que sus celdas ocupen posiciones consecutivas en memoria:

```
[0][0] [0][1] [0][2] [0][3] [0][4] [1][0] [1][1] ...
```

Así que si quieres recorrerla con un único `for` puedes usar un puntero simple:

```
int* ptr = (int*)matriz;
for( int i=0; i<25; ++i, ++ptr )
  std::cin >> *ptr;
```

En el caso general, es decir, que la matriz no ocupe posiciones consecutivas de memoria (por ejemplo un puntero doble dinámico), o si bien es porque quieres hacerlo de forma explícita, puedes calcular la fila y la columna a las que pertenece a cada índice:

```
for( int i=0; i<25; i++ )
{
  int fila = i / 5;
  int columna = i % 5;

  std::cin >> matriz[fila][columna];
}
```